# Latex creating table with less columns than it should

Tags: tables

I followed this instruction on how to create a table:
https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{5em} | m{5cm}| } 
\hline
Coefficient& Context& Possible_values& Function\\ 
\hline
$E(x)$& Algorithm_result & $-$& Error rate\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

however, instead of 4 columns, I get 2 columns
What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: if you get error messages the pdf is not intended to be usable, you specified two columns `m{5em} | m{5cm}` one 5em wide and one 5cm wide you also get errors about math from `_` use `\_` to get an underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify 4 columns, but you only specified two. Also `_` is a math mode command to make a subscript, you need `\_` to get an underscore.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | } 
\hline
Coefficient& Context& Possible\_values& Function\\ 
\hline
$E(x)$& Algorithm\_result & $-$& Error rate\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\begin{tabular}{<col spec>}` requires you to define each of the columns within `<col spec>`. If you want 4 columns, you need to provide the specification for each column. In your case, you only provided the specification for two columns: `m{5em}` (for both). You may be interested in something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ | *{4}{l |} } 
  \hline
  Coefficient &     Context       & Possible\_values & Function   \\ 
  \hline
     $E(x)$   & Algorithm\_result &      $-$         & Error rate \\ 
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Note that `*{<num>}{<col spec>}` replicates `<col spec>` a total of `<num>` times. Also, `_` is restricted to use within math mode. In order to use it in text mode, escape it `\_`.